# How do you get the OAuth token from the JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I have a page that is supposed to get the comments form a facebook object and post them on the page using JavaScript, but when the user logs in I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the OAuth token. Here is my page.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'myrealappid',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true,
        });
    };
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
    function getComments(objectid) {
//I need to append the OAuth token to this graph request
        var commentUri = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + objectid + "/comments";
        return $.getJSON(commentUri, function (json) {
            var html = "<ul>";
            $.each(json.data, function (i, fb) {
                html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</li>";
            });
            html += "</ul>"
        });
        $('.comments').html(html);
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getTripComments(data.WallPostId);
    });
</script>
<div id="pageLogo">
    <img src="/images/page_logo.png" alt="Digital Mementos" />
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook to Comment</div>
    <div id="comments">
    </div>
</div>
```

See where it says 'I need to append the OAuth token to this graph request'? Yeah, I need to do that. How do I get the OAuth token? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the part where you need to check for authentication. Read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) under `status & sessions.`

If you check the following you won't need the access token as Fisch stated:

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {

     });
   } else {

   }
 });
```

If an access token is still needed you can get it like this:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;

   } else {

   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! The link and code were useful. I'm still figuring out the 'right' way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making the request to the fully qualified endpoint, use Facebook's JavaScript method [FB.api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/).  When you use this method, you don't need to worry about the token.